# Galactic thief with a parasitic invisibility coat and a scepter containing a spirit from a past race

Tags: story-identification

More than 30 years ago I read a snippet of a story about a thief or scavenger. Either he had an order to procure a scepter or he had the scepter already and was looking for a customer.

What was special about him was that he had a coat that made him invisible. But the coat was a living organism, like a symbiont or parasite, that took his energy. So he could not use it too long or too often.

The scepter was the relic of a past civilization or long-gone alien race. The spirit of one of the alien race was captured in the scepter and a cat was similarly connected to it as the organic manifestation of that member of the alien race. But the spirit and manifestation could not unite.

The thief, when exhausted from using the coat, saw the spirit like a goddess in his dreams trying to tell him something.